# Is it possible to change the exposure compensation on a Olympus OM-D in Manual Mode?

Tags: astrophotography

Is it possible to change the exposure compensation on a Olympus OM-D in Manual Mode?
ISO, SS, and F all are set manual for star photography

Comment: What would you expect exposure compensation to do when in manual mode?

Answer (score 4):

When everything (exposure time, F-stop and ISO) is set to manual, there is nothing else left that could influence your exposure. All the factors for changing exposure are set by yourself, exposure compensation would have nothing left to do. So (without knowing that specific camera): No, it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I have to change my ISO.